# Issue with responsive dropdown navigation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navigation, dropdown

Hi guys hope you can help me for some reason my mobile version navigation dropdown menu gets cut down when moving to a real small screen. When the screen is bigger I don't have any issues but when browser is at its smallest it cuts the ("Tours and Daytours") nav in half. I think the problem lies within .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu class but not sure how to fix it.

[image]

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("Menu")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```

```css
/*hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). 
 Show the list item that contains the link to 
 open and close the topnav (li.icon) */

.Menu li:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.Menu li.icon {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* The "responsive" class is added to the Menu with JavaScript 
 when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the Menu look good 
 on small screens */

.Menu.responsive {
  position: relative;
}
#TA_socialButtonIcon936 {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: none;
}
.Menu {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 54%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Menu.stick {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.Menu.responsive li.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -4px;
  border: none;
}
.Menu.responsive ul li.icon a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.Menu.responsive li {
  float: none;
  display: inline;
}
.Menu.responsive li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #161616;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
/*Dropdown arrow for link items*/

.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px dashed;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: #161616;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
/* links inside the dropdown*/

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-top: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
  border-right: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.dropdown-menu a:last-child {
  border-top: 0;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: #755378;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  right: auto;
  left: -151px;
  bottom: -47px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Menu">
  <!--Nav-menu-->

  <!--Social media button-->
  <div id="TA_socialButtonIcon936" class="TA_socialButtonIcon">
    <ul id="Ug7Rjth" class="TA_links amVFTKsFPp">
      <li id="pyCAn7LGV" class="eYF1SLHKaeE">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g312578-d2284717-Reviews-Felleng_Day_Tours-Johannesburg_Greater_Johannesburg_Gauteng.html">
          <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/socialWidget/20x28_white-21690-2.png" alt="media-icon" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--End Social media button-->

  <ul>
    <!--Start Main ul-->



    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="DropDown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tours <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Tours</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Day Tours</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <!--End main ul-->
</div>
<!--End Nav-menu-->
```

Comment: Did you check your snippet? Doesn't show the same way as how you have in the picture. Can you make an exact problem, which is replicable using [mcve]?

Comment: I am sorry man not always sure how to implement code into stack overflow. This was my responsive css page should I have given my main css stylesheet aswell? But on the other side I managed to fix the navigation by removing the overflow from the .Menu class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s cutted because:

```
.Menu has {overflow: hidden;} //remove this line
```

And set width for dropdowns

```
.dropdown-menu { width: 200px;}
```

Comment: Ahhh man this worked pefectly, I completely forgot to remove the overflow property for I was testing the icon button of the trip advisor icon. would have forgotten completely of that property.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use media query on your css to set size width